# Mongoose is not setting defaults

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am not able to successfully set default values in MongoDB with Mongoose, I just get response code 500. Why won't they save? Here is my schema and the object I'm trying to save:

```
// Schema:

const eventsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      uuid: { 
        type : String, 
        default: 'test'},
      email: { 
        type : String, 
        default: 'test'},
      imageUrl: {
        type : String, 
        default: 'test'},
      voteCount: {
        type : Number, 
        default: 9},
});
```

```
// data object:

  photoDataObject4: {
    uuid: undefined,
    email: undefined,
    imageUrl: undefined,
    voteCount: undefined
  },
```

Comment: response code `500` means internal server error try to log the error message and let us know what  the error is, so that we can help you out

Comment: Without seeing all the code I think you are missing the `new` keyword when creating your mongoose schema

Comment: Please show us your code which is not working. Not unless we see the code, can we debug it.